# Dynamic variable after closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following code:

```
element.onclick=function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
};
```

I would like to do this:

```
for(k in array)
    element.onclick=function(e,array_value){
        console.log(e.target.value,array_value);
    }(e,array[k]);
```

However, I want `e` to retain access to the `window.event` object without explicit reliance on `window.event`. Essentially, I want whatever is usually passed via the first argument of an event listener to remain as such.

Is this possible?

Comment: Also, I'm aware that `e.target` won't exist because it doesn't exist in the scope that the closure was called.

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you want to do that?